# A joyful song for all to hear

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Figure out what each line is referring to, put them together, and then sing it loud for all to hear.

> I create and repair, but don't often destroy. You use my eye but I cannot see.
>   Who? Me. When? Now. Why? Because. Where? ...
>   A man who looks after the pennies, is very wise indeed.
>   Look into the night sky, a blinking light you will see, its not a UFO, but the __, yippee!
>   Once you've figured out the next line, tell me the name of the important women in his life.
>   This man hates figs and Romans.
>   On Earth, we have weight, but in space, we don't. However, our __ remains constant.

Comment: It's a bit early for this song.

Comment: @rhsquared Halloween is over, so its time for the next holiday

Comment: Exactly. But I don't think this question is about Diwali.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure I agree with the timing of this puzzle, because

I create and repair, but don't often destroy. You use my eye but I cannot see.

> SEW

Who? Me. When? Now. Why? Because. Where? ...

> HERE

A man who looks after the pennies, is very wise indeed.

> IT

Look into the night sky, a blinking light you will see, its not a UFO, but the __, yippee!

> International Space Station, or ISS

Once you've figured out the next line, tell me the name of the important women in his life.

> MARY

This man hates figs and Romans.

> Cursing the fig tree and being crucified => CHRIST

On Earth, we have weight, but in space, we don't. However, our __ remains constant.

> MASS

This refers to the lyric

> “So here it is, Merry Christmas” which is a line from the song “Merry Xmas Everybody” by Slade.

Comment: You have the last 3 clues correct, the others are not.

Comment: Oops sorry the third clue is also correct.

Comment: The third line could be rot13[fnire/fnivbhe]?

Comment: @jafe do you mean the fourth line?

Comment: 3rd in the OP, 4th in your answer :)

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: I'm afraid @jafe isn't correct :P

Comment: Is my first line correct, @AHKieran?

Comment: @El-Guest yes (the shorter word)